# Why does my wifi keep doing this?

Tags: updates, wifi, networking

This started happening after the OS update today.

```
[ 1518.424042] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[ 1518.434738] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[ 1518.596434] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[ 1518.596441] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[ 1518.607044] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[ 1518.768421] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[ 1518.768428] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[ 1518.779197] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[ 1518.940637] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[ 1518.940643] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[ 1518.951280] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[ 1519.112515] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[ 1519.112520] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[ 1519.123068] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[ 1519.283874] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[ 1519.283880] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
...
```

This is my network setup:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
```

This is my kernel:

```
Linux dylan-X550LD 4.4.0-79-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please help, it's annoying when your wifi keeps disconnecting and won't work until you shutdown and restart your laptop. A reboot doesn't work.

Here's my over all:

```
                                     dylan@dylan-X550LD
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee           OS: elementary OS 0.4.1 loki
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee        Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-79-generic
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee      Uptime: 8m
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee    Packages: 2982
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee   Shell: zsh 5.1.1
eee    eee            eee       eee  Resolution: 1366x768
eee   eee            eee        eee  WM: Mutter(Gala)
ee    eee           eeee       eeee  WM Theme: elementary
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee  CPU: Intel Core i5-4210U CPU @ 2.7GHz
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee  GPU: GeForce 820M
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee  RAM: 1066MiB / 3835MiB
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee  
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee   
    eeeee                 eeeee     
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee       
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Comment: same happened to my old hp laptop. haven't found a cure (it happened on all distros I tried)

Comment: I also noticed one more thing, happens only while playing DotA, dammit Gaben